# Inserting multiple values of an array into database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to read a file of data and insert into a table in mySQL. I have tried building an array and imploding, as well as a foreach loop like this one but only get back the first row of the table.

```
<?php 
$str = file_get_contents('-');
$con = mysqli_connect('-', '-', '-','-');
$dataArray = explode("|",$str);
$blahArray = array();
foreach($dataArray as $info){
            $pD = unserialize($info);
            $pD->*->*->*;
            $pL = $pD->*->*->*[0];
            $blah = $pL->BLAH;
            array_push($blahArray,$blah);       
}
foreach($blahArray as $val){
            $sql = "INSERT INTO table (BLAH)
                    VALUES('$val')";            
            mysqli_query($con,$sql);
            }
?>
```

I have a lot more datafields to enter but for debugging am just trying the one. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you getting any errors?  So are you saying that only the first `INSERT` you do is successful?

Comment: No errors, just a success that one row was added but there should be 90.

Comment: You should post the schema for the `property` table including the info for the primary key column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say for certain what is wrong with your code, but here is a modification you can make which might tell you what is going on:

```
foreach($apnArray as $val) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO property (APN) VALUES('$val')";            
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    if (false===$result) {
        printf("error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
    }
}
```

Check for two things.  First, make sure that you are in fact looping 90 times.  Second, see if each `INSERT` query be executing with or without error.

**Update:**

Based on your comment, it appears that you have a primary key with a unique constraint, which is *not* set to autoincrement.  In your `INSERT` query, you are only setting a value for the `APN` column and nothing else.  This means that MySQL is using a default value (0) for this primary key.  The solution to your problem is to pass in a unique value for the primary key *or* to set that primary key column to autoincrement.

Comment: So now I am getting this error 90 times!: error: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: Okay great, I see now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO property (APN)
                    VALUES";
foreach ($apnArray as $val) {
    $sql .= "('$val'),";
}
$sql = trim($sql, ",");
mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```